# vb.net recolour

Tags: vb.net, colors, picturebox

i'd like to know how can i correct this function 
in my project,

My plan is to

make my picBox2 become bitmap

get RGB pixels from it

then put it back into a new bitmap
after that i can use this function to convert my image's color

i wrote it like this :

```
    For row = 1 To 300
        For col = 1 To 300
            'MsgBox(row, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "DEBUGSHIT")

            PixelColor = BitMapforRGB.GetPixel(row, col)
            PixelColor = BitMapforRGB.GetPixel(row, col)

            R = (PixelColor.R + vsbRed.Value) * 0.5
            G = (PixelColor.G + vsbGreen.Value) * 0.5
            B = (PixelColor.B + vsbBlue.Value) * 0.5

            Dim newColor As New Color
            newColor = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B)

            RGBtoBitmap.SetPixel(row, col, newColor)

        Next
    Next

    'I try to change it to 
    'Dim MyShade As Color = ColorTranslator.FromOle(
    '   RGB(Red(row,col),Green(row,col),Blue(row,col))
    'but it seem not right.

    Dim reColor As New Bitmap(Me.pixBox2.Image)
    pixBox2.Image = reColor
End Sub
```

p.s: this error is 
Parameter must be positive and < Height.

Parameter name: y

Comment: Is it the `RGBtoBitmap.SetPixel(row, col, newColor)` line that throws the exception?

Comment: no, i am thinking about use different way to debug it, but i am quite confuse, i am new to VB..

Comment: Please for next question make sample as small as possible (i.e. in this case it should be something like `PixelColor  = BitMapforRGB.GetPixel(0, 300)`). Also foul words don't make you question more attractive, so avoid s#$#@$ and any other words in public samples, and your own code will not suffer much if you avoid them there too.

Answer (score 1):

You should have iteration from 0 to size of the image. I.e. 0 to `BitMapforRGB.Width-1` for `col`.